# Registering on long GC time events in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is it possible to get a notification when a long GC cycle occurs?

I'd like to write to our specific log when this happens.

Comment: This is JVM specific.  Which JVM do you use?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not within the jvm, but you can start Java with the `-verbose:gc` option, this should create console output like `[GC 511K->105K(1984K), 0.0029585 secs]`. [1](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22156)

With some clever scripting you then can build an alert system on long GC cycles.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reading that here http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/gc_tuning_5.html , section 3.2 has good information about this.

Comment: I was looking for a quick solution from within the JVM, don't feel like messing with 'clever scripting' :)

Comment: There is no build in way (that I am aware of), you could use something like VisualVM to monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to log the activity of the garbage collector using [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/). Typically it is used to monitor the performance of large-scale java applications. Maybe this solution is a bit too full-blown for your needs but at least you would be able to monitor what the gargabe collector does.

[JConsole](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) is a nice littel tool that makes use of JMX to display some performace data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could poll the [GarbageCollectorMXBean](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html) and look out for the [collection time](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html#getCollectionTime()) jumping up.